# Difficulties using Janusgraph indexes with Gremlin UNION

Tags: indexing, union, gremlin, janusgraph

I have an issue using UNION operator: in this first example the query works but gives no result:
`g.V().has('name','Barack Obama').union(has('name','Michelle Obama'))`

Instead in this second example the gremlin compiler replies that cannot use indexes:
`g.V().union(has('name','Barack Obama'), g.V().has('name','Michelle Obama'))`
`Could not find a suitable index to aswer graph query and graph scans are disabled: [()]:VERTEX`

Am I wrongly doing this type of query or has Janugraph some limitations?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the error message, probably related to the fact you are trying to start a new traversal inside the `union` step.

I think this is the query you are trying to run:

```
g.V().union(has('name','Barack Obama'), has('name','Michelle Obama'))
```

or even better:

```
g.V().has('name', within('Barack Obama', 'Michelle Obama'))
```

Comment: Your first query gives me the same error message as my second. The error is thrown because I disabled scan query, as I wanted to test the index usage by the UNION  operator. For this reason your second query (that works) is not exactly what I'm searching for.